# yt-dlp : How can I have separate file format for playlists and single videos

Tags: config, youtube-dl, playlist, yt-dlp

I have an `urls` file where I store all links I want to download. I download from it using `yt-dlp -a urls`.

For playlists I'd like to put videos into a folder, like it's shown in documentation examples, while for single videos I'd like to keep the separate file format though.

How can I do it with a single configuration file? If it's not possible with a single configuration file, I'd want to have other options in a single common place.

**Note:** In documentation I saw `TYPES:` in `--output`, but I don't know how to use it and if it's applicable to my case.

**PS:** If it's possible to write a wrapper using `yt-dlp` as a library, with a hook, it'd be a viable options

Comment: Yes, you would write a python script that used yt-dlp and took custom arguments. If you are capable of this it is the best way.